# TypeScript Breaking the loop after entry is found

Tags: typescript

This is more of a How to make this better type question then it is that this is completely broken.

I read now that Typescript doesnt allow for a Foreach to be broken so is there any other loops that allow data access of the current entry and then have it break once that is found and set:

```
 login(surName, passWord){    
    const name = this.members.find( x => x.surname === surName)
    const pass = this.members.find( x => x.password === passWord)
    if(name && pass){
      this.members.forEach(element => {
        if(element.surname = surName){
            this.persist.setPersistence(surName, element.color);
            return;
        }
      });
    }else{
      alert("User Details are incorrect please make sure your username and password is correct");
    }
  }
```

Once the surname and members color are found I want the loop to end this is scuffed so im curious what your take on this would be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to stop or break a `forEach()` loop other than by throwing an exception. If you need such behavior, the `forEach()` method is the wrong tool.

Early termination may be accomplished with:

- A simple `for` loop
- A `for...of / for...in` loops

example:

```
for (const element of this.members) {
    if(element.surname === surName){
        this.persist.setPersistence(surName, element.color);
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah Ya that makes a bit more sense thank you